# sqlplus: get parameters of file.sql execution

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

From a bat file I am using a process which is calling SQL/Plus in the same way:

```
@echo off
start sqlplus user/password@instance_name file.sql <instance_name>

echo End of process
pause
```

Inside file.sql I have something like :

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET VERIFY OFF
SET SCAN ON
SET HEADING OFF
SET RECSEP OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET BLOCKTERMINATOR OFF

set instance_name=<FROM PARAMETER>

SET VERIFY ON
SET HEADING ON

EXIT
```

How can I get the name which I am passing as parameter in SQL/Plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&1`

---

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374) the SQL/Plus command has the syntax:

> `SQLPLUS [ [Options] [Logon|/NOLOG] [Start] ]`

Then the [`START` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169914):

> #### Start
>
> `@{url|file_name[.ext]} [arg ...]`
>
> Specifies the name of a script and arguments to run. The script can be called from the local file system or from a web server.
>
> SQL*Plus passes the arguments to the script as if executing the file using the SQL*Plus START command. If no file suffix (file extension) is specified, the suffix defined by the SET SUFFIX command is used. The default suffix is .sql.
>
> See the [`START`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve044.htm#SQPUG127) command for more information.

Then for the `START` command:

> *`arg ...`*
>
> Data items you wish to pass to parameters in the script. If you enter one or more arguments, SQL*Plus substitutes the values into the parameters (`&1`, `&2`, and so forth) in the script. The first argument replaces each occurrence of `&1`, the second replaces each occurrence of `&2`, and so on.