# How to pass unix variable in where condition of query?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a file whose filename I am storing in a shell variable and I wish to pass that variable in the WHERE condition of my SQL select query. How can I achieve this ?

**my code**

```
cd /path/to/folder
var =$(ls tail)
id_var=$(echo "$var" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
...
...
sqlplus -s user/pwd@db < mysql.sql > output.txt
```

**cat mysql.sql**

```
select * from Records where "GlobalId"='$id_var'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744928/sqlplus-get-parameters-of-file-sql-execution/70746071#70746071):

```sh
cd /path/to/folder
var =$(ls tail)
id_var=$(echo "$var" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
sqlplus -s user/pwd@db @mysql.sql "${id_var}" > output.txt
```

Then in `mysql.sql` use `&1` to substitute the first start argument:

```sql
select * from Records where "GlobalId"='&1'
```

*Note: `&1` is a substitution variable (and not a bind variable) so you will need to make sure that the value passed in does not perform any SQL injection attacks.*

Answer (score 0):

You can export the variable
export id_var
Then use envsubst command
envsubst < mysql.sql

This will substitute your variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).