# How to pass a parameter from shell script to SQL script?

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, scripting

I have 2 scripts - one shell and one sql.

My shell script is similar to this:

```
export nbr=&1 

runsql script_name.sql
```

Im trying to pass a parameter for nbr while running the script.

The corresponding sql script is as such:

```
insert into table1

select * from table2 

where year='&1'
```

I get the error as below:

```
"enter value for year: old 22: where year='$1') 
                       new 22: where year='commit')"
```

Comment: `$nbr` is used nowhere ...

Comment: i put nbr as a place holder to pass a parameter "year' that is used in the sql script. is that causing the error?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [sqlplus: get parameters of file.sql execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70744928/1509264)

Comment: You haven't shown `commit` being passed, so is that coming from whatever `runsql` is - either another script or a function in this script? Or on the command line when you call your shell script? The output is (partly - where is the prompt coming from?) what you see with `set verify on`, but you've shown `$1` not `&1`. So this doesn't seem to be what you are really running. It would really help if you showed your actual code, not something significantly different.

Comment: Runsql is a function in another script which has all essential orasql connections etc for running. The log file shows the output where &1 is replaced with "commit" which is actually from the runsql script. I corrected the $. Sorry about that! I basically am just trying to copy data from one table to another but it has hundreds of millions of records so im trying to insert them by year.

Comment: You need to provide all your code, so we don't need to guess it. Show your `runsql`

Answer (score 0):

I'll show how to deal with it easily with an example based on my own scripts.
In this script I define a simple function `run_sql(DESCR, SCRIPT, DATABASES)`, where

- DESCR - short description
- SCRIPT - sqlplus run arguments, ie script name and its parameters
- DATABASES - list of dbname defined above on which you want to run it

Then we can easily use it like this:

```
run_sql "1st script" "@sql1.sql param1" db1 db2
run_sql "2nd script" "@sql2.sql param1 param2 param3" db1 db2 db3
```

Here we execute:

- "sql1.sql" with 1 argument on db1 and db2
- "sql2.sql" with 3 arguments on db1,db2 and db3

And we save all output into own log files.

Full example with test output: https://gist.github.com/xtender/465951befeed7f0ae1a3fe112dcd7fe4

Simple script `test.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Here you can define your db connection strings:
db1=xtender/pass@PDB19C_11
db2=xtender/pass@PDB19C_11
db3=xtender/pass@PDB19C_11
#####################################################################
# functions:
# Function syntax: run_sql(DESCR, SCRIPT, DATABASES)
# where
#   DESCR - short description
#   SCRIPT - sqlplus run arguments, ie script name and its parameters
#   DATABASES - list of dbname defined above on which you want to run it
run_sql(){
  local DESCR="$1"; shift
  local SCRIPT="$1"; shift
  local databases=("$@")
  echo =================================================
  echo =   $DESCR
  echo = Going to execute $SCRIPT...
  read -a res -p "Enter 'skip' to skip this step or press Enter to execute: "
  if [[ $res = "skip" ]]
  then
    echo Skipping $SCRIPT...
  else
    echo Executing $SCRIPT...
    for db in "${databases[@]}"
        do
          local cur=${!db}
          echo Executing $SCRIPT on $db - $cur...
          sqlplus -L -S ${cur} $SCRIPT >>log-$db.log 2>&1
          echo Done.
        done
    echo =================================================
  fi
}
#####################################################################


# Here we execute a script "sql1.sql" with one argument "param1" on db1 and db2:
run_sql "1st script" "@sql1.sql param1" db1 db2

# Here we execute a script "sql2.sql" with 3 arguments on db1,db2 and db3:
run_sql "2nd script" "@sql2.sql param1 param2 param3" db1 db2 db3
echo ============================================
echo === Done
echo ============================================
```

Then we can create sql scripts, for example `sql1.sql` and `sql2.sql`: `sql1.sql` requires one argument and `sql2.sql` - 3 arguments:

sql1.sql:

```sql
select '&1' as output from dual;
exit;
```

sql2.sql:

```sql
select
  '&1' out1,
  '&2' out2,
  '&3' out3
from dual;
exit;
```